# Java requires implementing default method

Tags: java, interface, java-8

I have Base interface:

```
public interface Doable {
    void doAction(String str);
}
```

I have extending interface:

```
public interface DoubleDoable extends Doable{
  @Override 
  default void doAction(String str) {
      doOnce();
      doOnce();
  }

  void doOnce();
}
```

And I have an implementation:

```
public class Action implements DoubleDoable {
    public void doOnce() {
      System.out.println(123);
    }
}
```

However, it is not compiled, as: `Error:(10, 8) java: Action is not abstract and does not override abstract method doAction(java.lang.String) in Doable`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I assume your method is not called `do` as this is a reserved keyword in Java.

Comment: once you change the name `do` to something else you'll be fine.

Comment: Compiles fine in Java 8. Just need to use something else than `do` for the method name.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, which compiler version do you use? Mine is javac_1.8_101

Comment: @Aominè, didn't you think that javac will show another errors in case it was matter of naming `do`? I took it for example, it won't solve the problem

Comment: 1.8.0_144, but I doubt that it matters. If you're actually using that compiler, then you're probably compiling with a -source or -target flag set to 1.7 or lower.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, this was the issue - one of the modules had 1.6 source for some reason. Now it is OK. If you make it into separate answer, I will mark it as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Java 8 compiler, the only way that your code can cause that compilation error is if the value of the `-source` flag that is passed to the compiler is set to `1.7` or lower.

Something like:

```
javac -source 1.7 ...
```

If you're using maven, the property setting below will have the same effect.

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call method `do` because it's java reserved word. All list of Java keywords you can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

Comment: @Aominè changed. I mean give it name. Changed.

Comment: This was just for example, bad for this

Comment: It means that Java's reserved keywords can't be used for naming methods or variables